# Why indpectdb in django didn't create all table models?

Tags: sql-server, django, sql-server-2017, legacy-database, inspectdb

I have restored the database "AdventureWorks2017" into SQL-Server-2017 , which contains a lot of tables such as:

```
dbo.AWBuildVersion  
dbo.DatabaseLog  
dbo.ErrorLog  
HumanResources.Department  
HumanResources.Employee
...
```

I am using django==2.0.5 , django-pyodbc-azure==2.0.4.1 , pyodbc==4.0.23
I have tried to generate database in tables in django  models by using:

```
python manage.py inspectdb>models.py
```

but only three dbo.AWBuildVersion , dbo.DatabaseLog , dbo.ErrorLog tables generated in models and someother models that django generated such as AuthGroup , AuthGroupPermissions , DjangoMigrations ,...

What should i have do , to generate all table models?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) say that SQL-Server is not supported for this command:

> **inspectdb** works with PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite.

Maybe that is the cause of your problem.